# How to convert big decimal numbers to binary without using itoa?

Tags: c

I've been working on a program that converts UTF-16 to UTF-8, but I've been having trouble converting big numbers like 14846106 to binary. All binary converters that I found on the web break if the decimal number is 4 digits or more. I used itoa, worked flawlessly but problem arose when I tried to compile the program on Linux. So are there any other alternatives (besides snprintf which isnt even capable of converting from decimal to binary)?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdlib.h/itoa and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-itoa/ have implementations of itoa that you can use

Comment: itoa converts binary to (ascii) decimal.  If you want to convert ascii decimal to binary you can use atoi or strtoll or sscanf.  To convert UTF-8 or UTF-16 decimal to binary, you should first convert to ascii (converting variant digits to ascii digits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple recursive *to binary* algorithm.

```
to_binary(unsigned x) {
  if (x > 1) {
    to_binary(x/2);
  }
  putchar(x%2 + '0');
}
```

Comment: This converts binary to ascii binary.  No decimal is involved (though from the OPs question, it is not clear what they mean by "decimal" and "binary").